# electronics voltage sensitivity

Tags: 12v

I have a 12v battery directly powering a handful of electronic devices (router, modem, hard drives). 
These vary from `0.5a~2a` so I have breakers on the (+) lines into the 12v dc power plug.
I'm noticing when I charge the battery through a 120v wall charger, the battery outputs up to 14.1v and during discharge it dips to 12v. 
Since I would want to keep a constant, what device would I need to keep a constant 12v output from the battery during charging and discharge?
Would this dc/dc boost be a device that could help?
http://www.mini-box.com/DCDC-USB-200?sc=8&category=981

**edit** i think this actually solves my issue
[Clean 12v car power](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/73917/clean-12v-car-power)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're making a UPS.

You will need a stepup/stepdown voltage regulator between the battery/charger and your electronics. The regulator you linked is certainly fine, but if you don't need it to be so configurable you can definitely find them cheaper.

Comment: thank you! would i need a regulator for each line?  or do you think i can have 1 regulator from the 12v battery and connect to bus?  i was looking at this http://www.linear.com/product/LTC3780#orderinfo

Comment: You just need a single regulator that can handle combined current draw from the devices. The regulator you're looking at looks promising,however it's going to take work to implement it. Soldering the leads on ssop will be challenging. If you can't find a regulator with a high enough power rating, you can get multiple regulators that can handle them individually like http://www.pololu.com/product/2577